# Perl: Parsing * delimited file

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have an input text file **input.txt** as shown

```
a,2,3*b,4,5*c,7,3*
```

I have to print the numbers as follows

```
a,2,3
b,4,5
c,7,3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: regex solution is ../[^*]/

Comment: `perl -l -0052 -pe0` Try it with `-MO=Deparse` to see how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think a regex would help?  It's much easier to just do

```
tr '*' '\n' <input.txt
```

If you require a Perl solution,

```
perl -pe 'y/*/\n/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following regex

```
/[^*]/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input has records separated by `*`? We can set the *input record separator* `$/` to that value!

```
local $/ = "*";
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  print $_, "\n";
}
```

Example as one-liner:

```
$ printf 'a,2,3*b,4,5*c,7,3*' | perl -lpe'BEGIN{$/="*"}'
a,2,3
b,4,5
c,7,3
```

(`-l` auto-`chomp`s the input, and appends the output separator to the output. `-p` loops through all records of the input, performs the code, and prints the value of `$_`. We do not process the lines themselves, just change the record separators from `*` to `\n`.)

This works fine as long as the original data does not contain newlines: these are passed through unmodified. A `s/\n//g` substitution would largely solve that.

Comment: Or as an obfu^D^D^D^D optimised version: `perl -l -0052 -pe0` By putting the `-l` switch before the `-0` switch `$\ ` is not set to `*` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split for this:

```
 my $string = "a,2,3*b,4,5*c,7,3*";

 my @substr = split(/\*/, $string);

{
  local $, = "\n";
  print @substr;
}
```

Output:

```
a,2,3
b,4,5
c,7,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
 my $data = "a,2,3*b,4,5*c,7,3*";
 my $data2 = substr($data, 0, LengthOfSampleInputStringHere - 1);
 my @values = split('*',$data2);

 # Print and verify (Optional)
 foreach my $val (@values) 
 {
    print "${val}\n";
 }
```

**EDIT**

You can also use this Regex:

```
/([^\*]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

`$string =~ s/\*/\n/g;` should do all the replacements inline for you